# Regex rules to rewrite a URL with potentially two OR three parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite some URLs to make them more SEO friendly.

Base URL options are:

- `index.php?location=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]&partnertype=$matches[3]`
- `index.php?location=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]&partnertype=$matches[3]`
- `index.php?location=$matches[1]&partnertype=$matches[2]`

What I have that mostly works is this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^location/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?', 'index.php?
location=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]&partnertype=$matches[3]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('^location/(.*)/(.*)?', 'index.php?
location=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]&partnertype=$matches[3]', 'top');
```

This allows these to work:

- /location/city/skill/partnertype/
- /location/city/skill/
- /location/city/

However, it does not allow /location/city/partnertype/ to work!

I tried adding a third rewrite rule to make it work (below), but that breaks /location/city/skill/ which I also need to work.

Third rewrite rule I tried:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^location/(.*)/(.*)?', 'index.php?
location=$matches[1]&partnertype=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

I'm a regex noob so I'm pretty sure it's something within the part after /location/ in the regex, but I don't know where it might be. Any help?

Comment: How can you discriminate `/location/city/partnertype/` from `/location/city/skill/`?

Comment: Hey @horcrux, I think that's exactly what I'm dealing with. Two things we're considering:

1) make the /location/city/partnertype/ URLs have another folder to make them different from /skill/ at the end, eg /location/city/type/partnertype/ (where location and type are static)
2) Write a function to include both /partnertype/ and /skilltype/ under skill_type, regex /location/city/skill_type/, then swap in either skill or partnertype based on a custom query. More involved, but might work better.